# How to change Student class so that s1 == s2 return true when s1 = new Student() and s2 = new Student()?

Tags: java

In one of my interviews, an interviewer asked me:

Given a `Student` class and two objects `s1` and `s2`:

```
s1 = new Student();
s2 = new Student();
```

How will `s1 == s2` return `true`?

I told him to make `Student` class a singleton, but he said no, and that we have to make a change in the class level so that `s1 == s2` would return `true`.

Note: we need to change `Student` class. Please don't reply `s1=s2`.
Any clue?

Comment: we need to change in class level, s1=s2 is not class level change.

Comment: Override `equals` and `hashcode`?

Comment: `new Student()` will return a new Student instance

Comment: Are you sure, he was talking about == and not equals

Comment: they are both references that refer to different objects in memory, so s1 == s2 should obviously not return true. the '==' is not compared 'within that class', so how would you?

Comment: As mentioned we can (easily) make `s1.equals(s2)` return true

Comment: Java doesn't allow for operator overloading, such as ==. The closest you can do is provide an `.equals()` to do the comparison. The implementation of == is referential equality, which is only true of the variables point to the same object in memory.

Comment: @HemantPatel Yes it was clearly '=='.

Comment: Then the answer is: there is nothing you can in the constructor that would make `s1 == s2` afterwards.

Comment: What is "fixed" in your assignment? Were the two constructor calls part of the question, and *directly* after that comparing `s1 == s2` should be `true`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Comment: Maybe with some AOP or native code it could be possible?

Comment: Just posted an answer that changes the `Student` class's constructor and results in `s1==s2` being true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a trick, but will meet the requirements:

Change the `Student` constructor to throw some exception (I chose an unchecked exception, so I don't have to specify it in a throws clause):

```
public Student()
{
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

Now, assuming we are allowed to add a try-catch block:

```
Student s1 = null;
Student s2 = null;
try {
    s1 = new Student(); 
    s2 = new Student();
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
System.out.println (s1==s2);
```

This will print `true`, since both `s1` and `s2` are `null`.

Even if we don't catch the exception, `s1 == s2` will still be true after the two constructor calls (actually after the first constructor call, since the second one will never be executed), but we have to catch the exception somewhere in order to test it.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari well, if you are allowed to add a try-catch block you can simply add `s1 = s2` and be done. Accepting this answer really makes zero sense. It is the most complex way of achieving something you did not make the requirements clear for.

Comment: Instead of `try ... catch` you can write `if (false) ...` and achieve the same result.

Comment: @luk2302 can you do any other thing in Student class except above given solution to achieve this?

Comment: @luk2302 till now I accepted this and found some bit relevant. If I get some other answer better than this, I will change this for sure.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari you stated that you are supposed to change something in the `Student` class, this answer does MUCH more than that, it changes _something_ outside the class, if you are allowed to change _something_ outside of it there is nothing preventing you from doing either `if (false) ...` or `s1 = s2;`. The main takeaway is that your requirement is really, really broad and very bad and that either you or the interviewer did not understand the problem at hand.

Comment: @luk2302 that would certainly be cheating, since no code of the Student class will be executed at all in your suggestion.

Comment: In the `if (false) ...` case that is true, but since you added a try-catch you can easily simply add a single line after the two constructor calls stating `s1 = s2;` and be done with it, the calls to Student() will be run (even one more than in your example) and still it will evaluate to true, yes it is useless, but not more useless than the original task.

Comment: @luk2302 I only made a change outside the class in order to be able to evaluate s1==s2 to show that it's true. If I kept the original two lines of code, my answer would still result in s1==s2 being true.

Comment: Only if you assign `null` to them initially which was not part of the problem description.

Comment: @luk2302 well, if they are instance variables, they will be assigned `null` by default. If they are uninitialized local variables, they won't have any value, so either the `s1==s2` comparison won't be executed (if you don't include the try-catch block) or the code won't pass compilation (if you include the try-catch block and perform the comparison after it).

Answer (score 5):

The operator `==` check if two objects are the same.
You created two different equals object.
So they are not the same and `s1 == s2` will return false.
You have to redefine the method `equals` and check them with this method as follow:

```
s1.equals(s2)
```

The method [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.

Note that when you redefine the method equals you need also to redefine the method hashCode, as explicitly documentated in the description of equals method:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Generally ide (like IntelliJ, Eclipse or Netbeans) helps you writing a good implementation of both methods.

Considering this I suppose that the interviewer has asked something like *How will s1 equals s2* talking about it and you misunderstood it as *How will s1 (simble equals) s2*. Or he has explicitly written the operator `==` on the paper?

---

If the interviewer asked explicitly how to will

```
s1 == s2 // returns true
```

after creating the two objects as

```
Student s1 = new Student();
Student s2 = new Student();
```

The only possibility is to change the reference of s1 (or s2) as follow:

```
Student s1 = new Student();
Student s2 = new Student();

s1 = s2;  // new added line , or the same if you write s2 == s1

s1 == s2  // now is true
```

But this is a trick, infact you are testing that two different variables are referencing the same object.

You can have a similar behaviour assigning to both variables `null`, or another `Student` previously created. Basically any change to code that assign to `s1` the same reference of `s2` will work.

Comment: I think everyone is taking it as 'equals' but it was clearly '=='

Comment: probably your interviewer meant to ask about equals() but made a mistake. don’t give just short literal answers to interview questions. use it as a chance to explain what you know, your reasoning and problem solving skills.

Comment: Yes, Its was == thats why I replied Singleton but he wanted me to change in Student class.

Comment: You can't create instances of objects using the operator new and having the check with == returning true on different instances

Comment: to put it simply, if u used a new on a class then that results in an object construction on the heap. And if we are comparing two references using == which are like comparing two different memory locations on heap. It has to definitely return false. Singletons usually make constructors private, and expose a  construction method that return the same object reference with each call , if  it had created once.

Answer (score 2):

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java), `==` compares the reference. ie it compares if `s1` and `s2` are pointing to the same object. Since you are using `new` to instantiate both `s1` and `s2`, your requirement is just **impossible**.

Answer (score 1):

The only logical solution I see are trivial:

```
s1 = new Student();
s2 = new Student();
s1=null;
s2=null;
System.out.println(s1==s2);
```

or:

```
s1 = new Student();
s2 = new Student();
s1=s2;
System.out.println(s1==s2);
```

or:

```
s1 = new Student();
s2 = new Student();
s2=s1;
System.out.println(s1==s2);
```

as @user7 suggested in the comment

Comment: Or `s1 = s2` or `s2 = s1`

Comment: This is a possibility too.

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares object references, it checks to see if the two operands point to the same object (not equivalent objects, the **same** object). So I really think that the only way can be something like this:

```
@Override
public Student clone(){
    return this;
}
```

Maybe this will make the `==` operator work as you asked. This is horribly wrong to me because I don't think that this is the intended use of `clone()` method. Otherwise I do not have any other clues on how to make as you asked considering the constraint of working at class level.

If `clone()` cannot be used maybe the answer will be: it is not possible to do that.

Answer (score -3):

As == operator compares objects references, I think that s1 and s2 has to be null.

Comment: `s1 = new Student();` cannot result in `s1` being `null`.

Comment: Yes, but it's the only way to obtain the expected response

Comment: No, `s1 = s2;` is another option. And even then you would need to elaborate on your answer + reasoning.

Comment: Deepak Tiwari said that s1 = s2 is not an option :-)

Comment: Okay, I will not argue further: this answer is bad and my downvote will remain here.

Comment: If you find another way to answer to this question, i make the promise to vote for your solution

Comment: @luk2302, David is right, the only way to make s1 == s2 is to set them as null.